# What should be taken into consideration when deploying Windows 8 in a domain environment?

Tags: windows-8, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-domain

*Edit: Reformulating the question:*

We have ordered new laptops but before they arrive, our development team is trying to decide whether to install Windows 8 or stick with Windows 7. We have already tested on isolated machines, but we have not yet been allowed to add the machines to the domain.

Before we approach the networking group to discuss adding Windows 8 machines to the domain, we need more information on what changes / issues to expect in moving from Windows 7.

Are there any aspects we should consider that are specific to Windows 8 clients?

Thus far, I've gotten the following feedback:

- New set of Group Policy templates
- Changes to proxy server settings

Additional items along these lines would be helpful.

We're not looking for items related to Windows GUI changes, but instead primarily items related to having the machine live and be used on the domain.

*Edit*

To reiterate, we have tested on isolated machines and do not currently have the ability to test ON THE DOMAIN.

Comment: What makes you expect it will work "differently"?  "Differently" how? What's your specific concerns? What's actual problem are you running into?

Comment: We've tested Windows 8 on our personal machines and are very happy with it. However, our networking group is hesitant to run with it on day one. With Windows 7, we plugged into the network and all went well. Are there known issues or significant changes with Windows 8 that could cause problems or additional work for the networking team?

Comment: Windows Administrative shares are disabled by default in W8, might be a problem....http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-administrative-shares.htm

Comment: @techie007 Can someone please help me to form this question so that it will not be closed and also help us to decide whether to use Windows 8 now vs later?

Comment: Please try to expand your question in regards to what aspects you're specifically concerned about (group policies, network security guidelines, ...). And please mention what Windows version you have currently deployed on your clients.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I created a new question seemingly at the same time you were editing this one. What should I do?

Comment: @GaTechThomas: Edit this one and delete the other one please :) For further assistance -> [chat]

Comment: The problem (IMO) is that this question is too localized to your specific usage and environment to be answered effectively.  Try it, if it works, great! If it doesn't, boo..  When upgrading to a new OS, application compatibility problems are usually WAY more of a problem then domain connectivity.  If you are coming from Windows 7, then it should be fine, if you're coming from XP, you'll have the same pains that going to Windows 7 would present (including the [restricted admin shares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share#How_to_enable_in_Windows_Vista_and_Windows_7)). :)

Comment: Just test it yourself...problem solved...this is way to localized.

Comment: Admin shares are in fact enabled when operating on a domain

Comment: @GrahamWager Updated the question per your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As techie007 says you might need to define what you mean by "differently" if you're digging for something specific here.

From the small amount of testing we've done, it behaves largely the same way however you use it - the start screen is still the start screen, etc.

It has its own set of group policy templates too - you can't expect to just drop it into a Windows 7 domain with Windows 7 specific policies and expect all your settings to work without proper testing. Some areas we've had problems with are things like proxy server settings, which is a concern for metro style apps, as more than a few of those are all about consuming / aggregating web content.

Comment: We don't know what we don't know, so your type of answer is exactly what we're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Your best option would be to install [Windows 8 Enterprise evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx) and simply find out. It's there specifically for these kinds of questions. Nobody is going to be able to tell you how Windows 8 will behave in your environment and with your programs.

For example, when we upgraded a few remote desktop servers to 2008 R2 we found our terminal emulator program occasionally likes to run up the CPU usage for no good reason and wreck usability for everyone else on the server. This is a program from a company I doubt any of you have ever heard of, and nobody else would have been able to give us a warning about. Your network is a unique beast.

Other than that you might need to craft some new GPO's specifically to control your Windows 8 machines, and lock users out of settings appropriately. For example, are they able to associate their Hotmail account to their login in any way, or is this covered under 'Disallow Local Login'? Do you really *want* them to have anything to do with Hotmail?

Comment: We have MSDN subscriptions. Licenses are not the issue. Wasted time is. If someone out here knows of significant changes or issues, then it would save everyone some time.

Comment: @GaTechThomas What made you think I was talking about licenses? If there was a major and glaring issue about "putting Windows 8 on a network" then it would be all over the Internet. You didn't even mention your forest level, or anything _remotely_ specific about your network. If doing a test install is a potential waste of your time then don't even bother thinking about upgrading until you're forced to.

Comment: @GaTechThomas *Licenses are not the issue. Wasted time is.* I agree. So please live up to your own standards and *respect the time of people on SuperUser*. If you don't have the time to improve your question then respectfully, it is rather rude to expect people to devote lots of time to trying to figure out what you're after in order to answer you.

Comment: You cannot be serious. I don't live on this site like you guys do. I'm trying to contribute and I'm trying to get help here. I have requested help on reformulating my question, so back off. It is complete nonsense that you think that I am wasting others' time by asking a question here - this site is built on asking questions regarding things that others have done before.

Comment: I _have_ dogfooded it on my own machine. However I cannot put that machine on the network. I need to give plausible reasoning on adding a new OS, and I _thought_ that this forum was the right place to ask.

Comment: Uh, wouldn't it have to be Microsoft eating their own dog food?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Eh, I guess it depends on whether you consider your network your product. I'm on the help desk, so if I give somebody Windows 8 I'm willing to call it _my_ dog food. I wouldn't want to throw people on Windows 8 and say "Call Microsoft, not my prob."